I want to power four screens with the same feed but I want a uniform delay on each
Having failed to find an off-the-shelf solution that doesn't cost multiple $ thousands I want to see if I can build it myself
I want to watch sports with constant replay. My goal is to have four screens next to each other all showing the same game but each with a progressive delay. Something like this:

screen 01 - realtime
screen 02 - rt - 10 secs
screen 03 - rt - 20 secs
screen 04 - rt - 30 secs

I'm thinking I need 5 HDMI ports, 1 - in and 4 - out. And some way to split the incoming feed and push it out with the variable delays.
my first question would be how can I get a Raspberry Pi to support 5 HDMI ports?

I want to power four screens ... ... that means to apply the correct voltage, so that the screens turn on ... it has nothing to do with video inputs

maybe your first question should be how to get RPi to support an HDMI input?

You mean you want to receive 1 ATSC signal and output 4 with 0, 10, 20 & 30 second delay using 4 HDMI ports, correct? I've not heard of a consumer COTS product that does this. And the latest RPi only has 2 HDMI ports. So no easy solution comes to mind. That said, get a desk top PC, a ATSC tuner card and install (the back end of) Mythtv. W/that you can record OTA signals. Now put (the front end of) Mythtv on 4 different RPis and set them to playback the same recording but at 4 different starting points. Hence the (not quite zero), 10, 20 and 30 second delay.

Item https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834021/stream-raspberry-pi-to-other-raspberry-pis might be a starting place.

Question?  Why don't you just setup a DVR such as mythtv and then you can play,pause,rewind,fast forward, and etc at will.  Software like VLC has all the standard controls to playback the resulting video file.
